# HUGE problems using CodeDom compiler, can't use namespaces in the dynamic code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, codedom

I'm trying to create dynamically generated code based on user input (just like a mini-compiler). But my problem is that i need to use the PresentationFramework.dll assembly inside the dynamic code, and i don't know how to reference it.

I have already tried `Assembly.Load()` and `Assembly.Loadfrom()`. But all i get is an error saying:

> "Assembly not found"

I am used to doing this with the IDE (right click references and then add), but now i need to find some way to do this through code.

I need the assembly to use `System.Windows.Shell` to create custom jumplists.

This isn't just happening for this specific assembly, but for several others too. But this is the most important one, so if someone could help me with this i would be thankful.

So the baseline is: I need to use the namespace `System.Windows.Shell`. I need to reference this namespace fully through code (no IDE). How can this be done? And is it even possible?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate (C#).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the version of PresentationFramework you want when you need to add it as a reference. Basically, you will find it in :

```
\Program File\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework
```

(for 64-bit compilation, or 32-bit on a 32-bit OS)

or

```
\Program File (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework
```

(for 32-bit compilation or 32-bit on a 64-bit OS)

These are only the root folders. From here, you can go for example in "v3.0" or ".NETFramework\v4.0" for example.

So you just need to add a reference to a full "[path]\PresentationFramework.dll" instead of just "PresentationFramework.dll", for example:

```
"C:\Program File\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\PresentationFramework.dll".
```

Comment: omg i feel so stupid -,- I forgot that i was compiling for 32-bit and needed to use /Program Files ->(x86)<-/

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer straight from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saf5ce06.aspx):

> If your project references any
>   assemblies, you must specify the
>   assembly names as items in a
>   StringCollection as the
>   ReferencedAssemblies property of the
>   CompilerParameters you use when
>   invoking compilation.

Comment: if you mean the `// Add an assembly reference.
    cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add( "System.dll" );`
part then i've already tried that. It works when referencing assemblies like system.dll or system.windows.form.dll, but it just won't work for PresentationFramework.dll. That is what my problem is. But thanks for trying to help =)

Comment: Can you be more specific than ```it just won't work for PresentationFramework.dll```?